# How can I convert a string from a python requests module GET response to an array?

Tags: python, python-requests, get

Basically I am making to make a GET request to a public joke API like this:

```
import requests
url = "https://backend-omega-seven.vercel.app/api/getjoke"
response = requests.get(url)
text = list(response.text)
print(text)
```

Notice that I am trying to convert the string value of the response to a list, because that is the object the API is actually trying to give back. However, I get the following output:
`['[', '{', '"', 'q', 'u', 'e', 's', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', '"', ':', '"', 'W', 'h', 'a', 't', ' ', 'd', 'i', 'd', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n', ' ', 's', 'a', 'y', ' ', 'w', 'h', 'e', 'n', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', 'y', ' ', 'c', 'a', 'm', 'e', ' ', 'o', 'u', 't', ' ', 'o', 'f', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 's', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', '?', '"', ',', '"', 'p', 'u', 'n', 'c', 'h', 'l', 'i', 'n', 'e', '"', ':', '"', 'P', 'r', 'i', 'n', 't', '(', '\\', '"', 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!', '\\', '"', ')', '"', '}', ']']`
Basically it takes each individual character from the string response and appends it as an element of a new list. Obviously, that's not how I wanted it to work. In order to extract the contests of the joke, I need it to be the actual array (or list, the same thing in python) that the server wanted to respond with. How can I parse the value like that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `response.json()` to get a `list` from parsing the JSON.

```py
data = response.json()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe I didn't know about that method even though I have been programming in python for a couple years...